# Can't find Google BigQuery connector in Tableau Public Ver 2021.3.1

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api, connector

I can't find the Google BigQuery connector in the list of installed connectors in the Tableau Public Desktop app and could not find a way to install it. I use Version  20213.21.0917.1006 64-Bit on Windows 10. Did anyone encounter this problem and found a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for third party driver installation and configuration can be found at https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers

Comment: Thanks a lot, the DB says that no driver is required for GBQ. It seems that, compared to the full version, Tableau Public is quite limited regarding data sources...